# Как на карте отметить города?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

По учебе понадобилось сделать карту России с городами на ней. 
У меня есть таблица с названием города, количеством населения, областью, где расположен город и координатами города.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вывести это на карту по заданным параметрам с учетом количества населения?
Например, все города из кластера 1, большие кружочком, маленькие треугольником и так далее. Или просто,все кружочками, размер кружочка в зависимости от кол-ва населения.

---

### update

Продвинулся в данной области. Все оказалось не столь сложно.
Проекция рисуется Basemap_ом. Точки ставятся соответственно размеру или другому параметру.

Пример, просто для наглядности.

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\pkgs\proj4-5.2.0-ha925a31_1\Library\share'

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=43,urcrnrlat=80,\
            llcrnrlon=25,urcrnrlon=168,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()    
m.fillcontinents(color='#04BAE3', lake_color='#FFFFFF')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#FFFFFF')

#Try some town
lon = 91.41667
lat = 53.71667
x,y = m(lon,lat)
m.plot(x,y,'ro',markersize=5)

plt.title("ploting population of Rus Cities")
plt.show()
```

Хотел попробовать еще Albers Equal Area Projection, но пока не разобрался.

**UPDATE2**

Первый способ оказался не самым красивым и интерактивным.
Для новой попытки использовал Bokeh и GoogleMap API.
Импортируем все необходимое

```
    from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions, SaveTool, Circle,                         Diamond, Square, Triangle
    from bokeh.plotting import gmap
    import webbrowser    
    import pandas as pd
```

Для начала берем наши данные и сортируем по кластеру с помощью Панд:

```
# Read the data from xlsx file
df = pd.ExcelFile('try_lon_lat_cities.xlsx').parse(sheet_name='исходные данные',header=0, index_col=0)
# Drop missing values and reassinge data to object again
df.dropna(inplace=True) 
# Groupiong data by one cluster for future use as xs and ys for the plot
clustered_data = df.groupby(['cluster'])
cl1 = clustered_data.get_group(1)
cl2 = clustered_data.get_group(2)
cl3 = clustered_data.get_group(3)
cl4 = clustered_data.get_group(4)
```

Задаем параметры для гуглокарт:

```
#Configure Google map options
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=62.532422, lng=85.205159, map_type="roadmap", zoom=3)
GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'Enter_your_API_KEY_here'
p = gmap(google_api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY,
             map_options=map_options, title='My map')
```

Далее работаем с Bokeh:

```
#p.add_tools(PanTool(), WheelZoomTool(), BoxSelectTool())
p.add_tools(SaveTool())

#Sizing the glyphs
baseline = df['size'].min() - 1.0
scale = 1500

#lat lon data for each cluster
source = ColumnDataSource(
   data=dict(lat1 = cl1['lat'].tolist(),
             lon1 = cl1['lon'].tolist(),
             rad1 = [(i-baseline)/scale for i in df['size'].tolist()],
             legend1 = cl1['cluster'].tolist())
                         )
source2 = ColumnDataSource(
   data=dict(lat2 = cl2['lat'].tolist(),
             lon2 = cl2['lon'].tolist(),
             rad2 = [(i-baseline)/scale for i in df['size'].tolist()],
             legend2 = cl2['cluster'].tolist())
                         )
source3 = ColumnDataSource(
   data=dict(lat3 = cl3['lat'].tolist(),
             lon3 = cl3['lon'].tolist(),
             rad3 = [(i-baseline)/scale for i in df['size'].tolist()],
             legend3 = cl3['cluster'].tolist())
                         )
source4 = ColumnDataSource(
   data=dict(lat4 = cl4['lat'].tolist(),
             lon4 = cl4['lon'].tolist(),
             rad4 = [(i-baseline)/scale for i in df['size'].tolist()],
             legend4 = cl4['cluster'].tolist())
                         )

# Setting different shapes to use with each cluster
p.circle(x="lon1", y="lat1", size='rad1', fill_color="black", 
         fill_alpha=0.5, legend= "legend1", source=source)
p.diamond(x="lon2", y="lat2", size='rad2', fill_color="black", 
          fill_alpha=0.5, legend="legend2", source=source2)
p.square(x="lon3", y="lat3", size='rad3', fill_color="black", 
         fill_alpha=0.5, legend="legend3", source=source3)
p.triangle(x="lon4", y="lat4", size='rad4', fill_color="black", 
           fill_alpha=0.5, legend="legend4", source=source4)

p.legend.click_policy="hide"
# Use Chrome for the plotting
chrome_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path),1)
# legend='legend'
output_notebook()
output_file("gmap.html")
show(p, browser="chrome")
```

В итоге имеем кликабельную карту, которую можно увеличивать и уменьшать. Также можно отключать слои (кластеры) и смотреть данные по отдельности.
[image: карта]

Осталось лишь нессколько вопросов:

1. Как добавить легенду к карте, если использовать вот такой метод добавления глифов?

```
# Setting different shapes to use with each cluster
circle = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=20, fill_color="black", fill_alpha=0.5)
# Adding shaes of the clusters onto the map
p.add_glyph(source, circle)
```

У Circle нет такого метода, из add_glyph тоже не получается.

2. При попытке сохранить картинку через инструмент сохранения - сохраняются только точки, но не подложка гугло-карт. Как с этим бороться?

[image: странное сохранение]

Comment: Вы не пытались найти исходники в интернете ? Ваш вопрос очень огромен.
Как я вижу реализацию: Вам нужно получить карту россии и координаты городов. Реализовать функцию отработки данных и рисование на этой карте маркеров по данным. Но все же на питоне не представляю сколько нужно написать. Попытайтесь что - то сделать самому, вы же учитесь по этому языку и должны знать как реализовывать. А если у вас возникнет вопрос в частности кода то задавайте его. Никто писать за вас код не будет.

Comment: не владею питоном, однако мне попадались примеры использования питона в связке с d3.js, который отлично подходит для этой задачи